# Bash script showing error with mv

Tags: bash, shell, mv

I have a bash script that I placed in my git/bin folder and i'm launching that through git bash

```
currDir=$PWD
suf="_temp"
path=$currDir$suf
cd ..
mv $currDir $path
```

`currDir` would be `C:\git_init_fi` in my case.
I'm just trying to rename a folder but it keeps telling me

```
mv: cannot move '/c/git_init_fi' to '/c/git_init_fi_temp'
```

Comment: Well ... `example path` has a space in it. Your `mv` command does not have quotes around `$currDir`, so the effective command line would be `mv example path example path_temp`.  Does that look right to you?  (No, me neither.)  Perhaps you could update your question with some actual paths.  Oh, and also, quote your variables.

Comment: oh ok i edited it, sorry this is my first post.

Comment: @Zeyad, run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the problems it finds; you still aren't quoting correctly.

Comment: @Zeyad, ...note also that Windows is much pickier about when renaming directories is allowed than UNIX is; on Windows, you can't have any files inside that directory open (or the directory itself in use, including by the shell or any active shell extensions), so you could be getting that error for reasons that have nothing to do with your script being wrong, and everything to do with what else is going on in your OS environment.

Comment: @Zeyad, ...I'd suggest putting a `sleep 300` or such in your script, and when it's at that point in execution, checking whether you can rename the same directory from Windows Explorer; if you can't do it from Windows, then *of course* `mv` won't be able to.

Comment: ok thanks everyone for the suggestions, it turns out that just by initializing git in a folder it leaves a hook there and you can't rename a folder even if change the directory to be something outsider the folder itself.  It worked when I opened the shell outside the folder.